# Series RL current equation

Tags: current, resistors, inductor, differential

I am trying to derive a inductor current equation for \$i(t)\$ in a series RL circuit when the switch is closed at \$t=0\$, as seen below:

[image]

I have posted my attempt so far but I'm having trouble getting past a certain point which I have labelled equation (7) on my attached workings page.

I am unsure how to take the integral of the RHS of equation (7). I know the integral is the natural log, but I'm unsure of what happens inside the brackets.

I know what the answer should be and it can be seen circled at the bottom of my attempt page.

[image]

Comment: I would use Laplace, transforming i(t) into an I(s).

Comment: I actually never thought of that but I would rather learn this method first as this is the way I learned to derive capacitor I and v equations

Comment: https://physics.info/circuits-rl/

Comment: Thanks Andy, that’s quite helpful. But I still don’t understand that part. Where does the minus v/r come from on the top line after taking the integral? Is that a rule of integrating or is there skipped algebra steps there I am not seeing?

Answer (score 3):

Everything up to step 7 is correct so starting from there:
$${\int_0^t \frac{dt}{L\mathbin{/}R}=\int_0^i\frac{di}{V\mathbin{/}R - i}}$$
Multiplying both sides by \$-1\$
$${\int_0^t \frac{-dt}{L\mathbin{/}R}=\int_0^i\frac{di}{i - V\mathbin{/}R}}$$
You already have the integral of the LHS:
$${\frac{-t}{L\mathbin{/}R}}$$
To solve the right hand side, we can use integration by substitution ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution)):
$${let\  \ u=i-V\mathbin{/}R}$$
$${thus \ du=di}$$
Pluging \$u\$ back into the RHS of equation 7 yields:
$${\int_0^i \frac{du}{u}}=ln|u| \Big|_0^i$$
substituting \$u=i-V\mathbin{/}R\$
$${ln|i-V\mathbin{/}R|\Big|_0^i=ln|i-V\mathbin{/}R|-ln|0-V\mathbin{/}R|}$$
$${\rightarrow \ ln\Big|\frac{i-V\mathbin{/}R}{-V\mathbin{/}R}\Big|}$$
Equating both sides:
$${\frac{-t}{L\mathbin{/}R}=ln\Big| \frac{i-V\mathbin{/}R}{-V\mathbin{/}R}\Big|}$$
Taking both sides as a power of \$e\$:
$${e^{-t\frac{R}{L}}=-\frac{iR}{V}+1}$$
Solving for \$i\$
$${i=\frac{V}{R}\left(1-e^{-t\frac{R}{L}}\right)}$$

> **What if we didn't multiply by -1**

So we start again after step 7:
$${\int_0^t \frac{dt}{L\mathbin{/}R}=\int_0^i\frac{di}{V\mathbin{/}R - i}}$$
You already have the integral of the LHS:
$${\frac{t}{L\mathbin{/}R}}$$
To solve the right hand side, we can use integration by substitution ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution)):
$${let\  \ u=V\mathbin{/}R - i}$$
$${thus \ du=-di}$$
Pluging \$u\$ back into the RHS of equation 7 yields:
$${\int_0^i \frac{-du}{u}}=-ln|u| \Big|_0^i$$
substituting \$u=V\mathbin{/}R - i\$
$${-ln|V\mathbin{/}R - i|\Big|_0^i=-\left(ln|V\mathbin{/}R - i|-ln|V\mathbin{/}R - 0|\right)}$$
$${\rightarrow \ -ln\Big|\frac{V\mathbin{/}R - i}{V\mathbin{/}R}\Big|}$$
By law of logarithms:
$${aln(x) = ln(x^a)}$$
Thus:
$${-ln\Big|\frac{V\mathbin{/}R - i}{V\mathbin{/}R}\Big| = ln\Big|\frac{V\mathbin{/}R}{V\mathbin{/}R - i}\Big|}$$
Equating both sides:
$${\frac{t}{L\mathbin{/}R}=ln\Big|\frac{V\mathbin{/}R}{V\mathbin{/}R - i}\Big|}$$
Taking both sides as a power of \$e\$:
$${e^{t\frac{R}{L}}=\frac{V\mathbin{/}R}{V\mathbin{/}R - i}}$$
Solving for \$i\$
$${\frac{V\mathbin{/}R - i}{V\mathbin{/}R} = \frac{1}{e^{t\frac{R}{L}}}}$$
$${1 - i\frac{R}{V} = e^{-t\frac{R}{L}}}$$
Rearranging:
$${i=\frac{V}{R}\left(1-e^{-t\frac{R}{L}}\right)}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why do you multiply both sides by -1 on the second step down?

Comment: @David777 I multiplied by `-1` to make my life a bit simpler =]. I've updated my answer with the scenario where I don't multiply by `-1`. Please check it out and let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

To solve in the time domain, first re-arrange equation 2 in the form

\$  \frac{di}{dt} + \frac{R}{L}\,i= \frac{V}{L}  \$

This is a linear first order differential equation.  This class of equations can be solved by multiplying through by an [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor). In this case the integrating factor is

\$ e^{\small\frac{^R}{L}\normalsize t} \$

Multiplying through we get

\$ e^{\small\frac{^R}{L}\normalsize t}\, \frac{di}{dt} +  \frac{R}{L} \, e^{\small\frac{^R}{L}\normalsize t} \,i =  \frac{V}{L} \, e^{\small\frac{^R}{L}\normalsize t}  \$

By the product rule, the left side becomes

\$ \frac{d}{dt} \left( e^{\small\frac{^R}{L}\normalsize t}\,i \right) =  \frac{V}{L} 
 \, e^{\small\frac{^R}{L}\normalsize t} \$

Integrate both sides with respect to *t*

\$  \int\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{\small\frac{^R}{L}\normalsize t}\,i \right)\,dt = \frac{V}{L}\int e^{\small\frac{^R}{L}\normalsize t} \, dt \$

and we get

\$  e^{\small\frac{^R}{L}\normalsize t}\,i = \frac{V}{L}\,\frac{L}{R} \,e^{\small\frac{^R}{L}\normalsize t} + c\$, where *c* is a constant. Dividing through by \$ \,e^{\small\frac{^R}{L}\normalsize t} \$ we get

\$  i = \frac{V}{R} \, + ce^{-\small\frac{^R}{L}\normalsize t}\$

Solve for \$c\$ by setting initial conditions \$t=0\$ and \$\, i
_{(t=0)} = 0\$ to obtain

\$c = - \frac{V}{R}\$

Substitute for  *c* to obtain the solution

\$  i = \frac{V}{R} \,\left(1 - e^{-\small\frac{^R}{L} \normalsize t}  \right)\$